# Activity with multiple ViewModels

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I have an `Activity` that contains 3 `RecyclerViews`. I need populate `RecyclerViews` with data from remote repository (3 different requests). Can I use multiple `ViewModels` in the `Activity`, or is there any better solution (best practice).

Comment: Google sample of AAC showed the usage of 1 RecyclerViews with 
 1 LiveData. What is the issue if you try to do 3 RecyclerViews with 3 LiveDatas

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case I would recommend to use one view model which populates three different LiveData objects. This way the UI can get updated whenever one of your three requests gets a response. For details how to use a RecyclerView with LiveData take a look into the [Google Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java).

I think having multiple viewmodels per activity only increases complexity and I do not see any value in doing that.

Comment: The Google example link is dead.

Comment: @guglhupf There is a value in doing that: decreasing coupling between `RecyclerViews` and increasing the ability to reuse them independently or move to another screen.

Answer (score 57):

According to [the open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), you should create three different `ViewModel`s. The complexity isn't increased that much, and you are gaining the ability to move one `ViewModel` (or just reuse it) with the corresponding `RecyclerView` to the another `Activity` very easily.

Of course, sometimes breaking rules makes sense - for example if you know, there is no chance, that `RecyclerView` will be reused or moved to another screen, and then you can go for simpler solution with one `ViewModel`.

The same situation if the `ViewModel` (even with the 3 lists) is likely to stay always very simple (just three `LiveData` fields, just a few lines of code to populate them), you can break this rule.

However violation of O/CP is not a good practice - it's just a conscious breaking of rule.

Comment: Is it possible for `ViewModels` to communicate between each other? Let's say one `ViewModel` has `LiveData` object, that triggers `LiveData` in another `ViewModel`. Tying them together in `Activity` seems wrong, so how would you do this?

Comment: I don't know what is your use case but in general I'd avoid connecting one `ViewModel` to the another. I'd rather create another object and inject the same instance of it to the both `ViewModels`. Of course this third, common object can also have `LiveData` as a member, which one of the `ViewModel` can update and the other - observe. If you need more detailed info, please post a new question and I'd be glad to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

I got two recyclerview in a fragment. I think that use two ViewModels would be better. Cause different recyclerviews got their own data request, and state handling especially connections error.
In this case separate into different ViewModels would not increase the the complexity, but I think it well fit the rule of decupling

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, you can have one ViewModel, that uses one service class, which in turn uses the three repositories to get the data. For example:

`XActivity` --> `XViewModel` --> `XService` --> `{Arepository, Brepository, Crepository}`

Comment: This solution will make the coupling between `Activity`, `ViewModel` and `Service` very high so that moving one `RecyclerView` from `XActivity` to `YActivity` will be hard.